# java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Failed to allocate a 31961100 byte allocation with 15257484

Tags: android, exception, parse-platform, bitmap, imageview

i created listview which contain 25 rows. every row has a bitmap inside imageView. all bitmaps come from parse.com, when the listview show some times i am getting below type error.

```
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Failed to allocate a 31961100 byte allocation with 15257484 free bytes and 14MB until OOM
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. Well if you have 15 MB free, it is not very surprising that your program fails  to allocate 31 MB... Could you give some context, as such, pretty hard to give an answer... Oh, and also take some time to read http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One thing you may want to consider is storing a reference to your listview items and in a destroy method recycle all your bitmaps and clear the drawing caches of all your imageviews which will preserve memory.

I assume you're using a custom adapter so try adding this method:

```
public void recycleBitmaps()
{
    try
    {
        for (Bitmap bmp : myBitmapListThatIsPopulatingImageViews)
        {
            if (bmp != null)
            bmp.recycle();
        }
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

And make a call to this method every time your activity pauses

```
@Override
public void onPause()
{
    super .onPause();
    mListAdapter.recycleBitmaps();
}

@Override
public void onResume()
{
   super .onResume();
   reinitializeListAdapter();
}
```

This should save your memory. Let me know if that works.